# Apache, nginx, демон

Tags: apache, nginx, демон

Являются ли apache и nginx сетевыми демонами?

Comment: это вроде называется прокси(точно не знаю)

Comment: Да, являются. .

Comment: сначала приведите **используемое вами** определение «сетевого демона». только после этого можно будет дать объективный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Да. Любой сервис предоставляющий услуги по сети, является сетевым демоном. Даже вот такая конструкция. `watch -t echo qu-qu | sudo nc -l 443`